# Management of error log data files

Tags: c#, logging, uninstallation

I am using [SimpleLog](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/585796/Simple-Log). I have some related questions:

1. How long should you keep error logs for?
2. Should you delete all error logs with your uninstaller?

Comment: The answer (doesn't depends on the logger) is - it depends. Give us concrete scenario, otherwise question is opinion-based.

Comment: Ok. All exceptions reported by a C# dll library.